# Sql Pivot By Grouping two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot

[Sman Weekly Visit Party Wise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dE81G.jpg)

What I am trying to achieve here is to Group the Rows with same LedId_Sman and LedId_Party and then have a pivoted View of the Days visited in a single Row.

My Actual Table

```
LedId_Party LedId_Sman  VisitDay
----------- ----------- --------
426         296         3
426         296         6
441         296         2
```

Query I am Using

```
SELECT LedId_Party, LedId_Sman,[1]as Sun,[2]as Mon,[3] as Tue,[4] as Wed,[5] as Thu,[6] as Fri,[7] as Sat
FROM dbo.tbl_WeeklyVisit

Pivot(
Count(VisitDay) 
For VisitDay in
([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7]
))AS PiviotTable
```

This is currently what I Get

```
LedId_Party LedId_Sman  Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun
        426       297   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
        426       297   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
```

This is what I want the Output to be.

```
LedId_Party LedId_Sman  Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun
        426       297   0   1   0   0   1   0   0
```

I am Fairly New To SQL so an insight on how would it work would be very helpful and appreciated.

Comment: I think this is right just checked again result.


LedId_Party LedId_Sman  Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun
        426       297   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
        441       297   0   1   0   0   0   0   0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have extra columns in the data that are resulting in the extra rows.  When using pivot, it is a good practice to have a subquery with only the columns referenced in the pivot:

```
SELECT LedId_Party, LedId_Sman, [1] as Sun,[2] as Mon, [3] as Tue,
       [4] as Wed, [5] as Thu, [6] as Fri, [7] as Sat
FROM (SELECT LedId_Party, LedId_Sman, VisitDay
      FROM dbo.tbl_WeeklyVisit
     ) wv
PIVOT(Count(VisitDay) 
      For VisitDay in ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7]
                      )
     ) as PiviotTable
```